# How could I get square root of a symbol in python?

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am using math.sqrt in python to compute the squre root of something, but that "something" is a symbol instead of a known value. I am using that "something" as an intermediate variable for later use.

```
import math
from math import sqrt
x = Symbol('x')
y = math.sqrt(x)
print(y)
```

Hower I get the error message

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 207, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Looks like there's no other packages for me to compute square root except "math.sqrt", does anyone know how I could get rid of this problem?

Comment: This should not be closed. The user is using a library called sympy. I suggest the user should update the question to make it clear that Symbol() is coming from this library; this will clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

When using `sympy`, one should use the functions in `sympy` that operate on symbols, rather than the `math.*` functions that operate on floating point numbers, e.g.

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = sqrt(x)
print(y)
```

In this case, the code is using `sympy`'s `sqrt()` function.

Comment: In this context, it might be better to use `sympy.Symbol` and `sympy.sqrt`.